# Does `git lfs track` do more than writing to `.gitattributes`?

Tags: git, git-lfs

From my understanding `.gitattributes` works similar as `.gitignore`.
If I define a filter in `.gitattributes`, this filter will take effect and the files will be transferred to LFS.

In every GIT LFS related document (official documentation, stackoverflow answers, ...) it is recommended to run `git lfs track`.

Does `git lfs track` do anything else than writing the filter to `.gitattributes`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git lfs track` does two things: modify `.gitattributes` and adjust timestamps so that Git picks up any existing files and converts them to LFS objects.  In addition, it does some sanity-checking to avoid duplicates and common mistakes.

There's no reason you can't just modify `.gitattributes` yourself, but note that if you do that, you should also run `git add --renormalize .` to make sure that any existing files matching the relevant patterns are converted to LFS.

Comment: So basically if I add a new file to git that is not yet tracked it is save to only edit `.gitattributes` but if I want to convert an existing file to LFS I should use `git lfs track`.

Comment: You can use either technique for either case, but if your `.gitattributes` pattern matches existing files you need to run `git add --renormalize .` if you don't use `git lfs track`.  Your approach does work, though.